# sqldeveloper and cpanel

Tags: mysql, cpanel, oracle-sqldeveloper

i can't access my website mysql db from sqldeveloper.

in cpanel there is an option (Remote Database Access Hosts) which allows one to add IP addresses that can access the db. I have entered my ip address and i have used the % wildcard.

so for instance if my ip address was 12.34.56.78, i have entered my ip address as:

1 - 12.34.56.78

2 - 12.34.56.%

3 - 12.%.%.%

in sqldeveloper i have downloaded and added the mysql third party jdbc driver .jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar).

i have the right user name, password, hostname and port.

so, if my website domain was called www.mysite.com and my username was user, the username i would use in sqldeveloper would be mysite_user.

and the hostname would be www.mysite.com.

the port i am told via cpanel is 3307.

i bow to any superior knowledge if my assumptions are incorrect.

any help would be appreciated

-- edit --

oh yeah, the error message I get (pretty important!) in sqldeveloper is

Status : Failure - Test failed: Communications link failureThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

-- end edit --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i did need to use port 3306 but more importantly, my web host needed to make a change on their firewall.

i managed to connect using mysite.com, username, password and port 3306.

thanks @Achilleterzo for your help in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

I do the same via cPanel but after i connect to my host via SqlYog community edition...

Uniqe differce is the port, i use the standard 3306 port instead a custom port.

Try if it connect: http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/

Comment: thanks, tried it but get an error message: Error No. 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.mysite.com' (10060)

Comment: i've read up on this error message and it says that this problem is to do with the network: [link](http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html) i am wondering if i have the right hostname?? should i be using www.mysite.com as the hostname or should i be using the hostname of my web host?      url http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Comment: With my host account i can use my domain, with or without "www" (as CNAME of mydomain.com), is the port that make difference server side... Let your ip address without any wildcard, and try to connect to default port on your host leaving off "www"

Comment: still no connection ... tried mysite.com and both ports 3306 and 3307, will try my ip address in cpanel without any wildcards, says to wait up to 15 minutes tho.

Comment: still nothing ... i have a support call in with my web hosts (www.5quidhost.co.uk/) so i guess i'll have to wait for them to get back to me. unless you've (or anyone else) has any other ideas @Achilleterzo

Comment: Yes, at this point you need to wait if they have link correcly cPanel and MySql or what are the settings for connect to, i think... Another test you can try is to telnet your "host" "port" and see what you get

Comment: thanks, i tried that last night and tried it again just now. command i used was "o mysite.com 3307" and "o mysite.com 3306" and with the www's but nothing ... looks like a wait out job